# Projection of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, project

I want to calculate the projection u⟶v

Definition: proj(u⟶v)=u⋅v|v|2v

```
# my 2 vectors 
u<-c(1.5,sqrt(3)/2)
v<-c(2,0)
```

The answer should look as the following :

```
[1] 1.5 0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for.

```r
u <- c(1.5,sqrt(3)/2)
v <- c(2,0)

as.vector( (u %*% v) / (v %*% v) ) * v
```

yields

```r
[1] 1.5 0.0
```

You can wrap it into a function

```
proj <- function(u, v) {
 return(as.vector( (u %*% v) / (v %*% v) ) * v)
}
```

Comment: Upvote but you could name the function `proj`, right?

Comment: For sure. Didn't think of the name.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
library(mosaic)
u <- c(1.5,sqrt(3)/2)
v <- c(2,0)
project(u, v)
# 1.5 0.0

vlength(u)
# 1.732051

vlength(v)
# 2
```